# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int64'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a model that contains a collection of items, these items are displayed using an EditorTemplate.  If my model does not have a value for the Quantity field, I have no problems.  However, if the quantity property has a value, when the template view is rendered the following exception is thrown on the @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Quantity ... :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int64', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'
```

Here is the editor template.

```
@model OrderLineItemModel
<tr id="rowid-@Model.ItemID">
    <td class="itemidcell">@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ItemID) @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ItemID)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerItemID)@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.CustomerItemID)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemName)@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ItemName)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BlanketOrderQuantity)@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.BlanketOrderQuantity)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReleasedQuantity)@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ReleasedQuantity)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RemainingQuanity)@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.RemainingQuanity)</td>
    <td id="cellid-@Model.ItemID">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Price)</td>
    <td class="quantitycell">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Quantity, new {@class = "quantitytxt"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
</tr>
```

The line that is failing is this one.

```
<td class="quantitycell">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Quantity, new {@class = "quantitytxt"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
```

Quantity has a data type of Int64.  I'm not sure why the dictionary requires a String the second time and not on the initial rendering.

Here is the Controller Action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Release(ReleaseModel model) {          

        var errors = _orderProcessorService.ValidateOrder(model);

        if (errors.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var orderValidationError in errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError(orderValidationError.Name, orderValidationError.Description);
            }
        }

        if (! ModelState.IsValid) {

            return View(model);
        }


        var response = _orderProcessorService.SubmitOrder(model);

        var responseModel = new OrderResponseModel();
        if (response.OrderStatus == Enumerations.OrderStatus.Success) {
            responseModel.Message = "Thank you for submitting your order. Your sales representative will contact you with any questions concerning your order.";
            responseModel.OrderStatus = "successful";
        }
        else {
            responseModel.Message = "We are sorry, but something has happened during your order submission and your order wasn't processed successfully. Please contact your sales representative regarding this order submission.";
            responseModel.OrderStatus = "failed";
        }


        return View("OrderSubmitted", responseModel);

    }
```

Here is my Model that is being used for the template.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace ViewModels.BlanketOrder {
    public class OrderLineItemModel  {
        [Display(Name = "Customer Item #")]
        public string CustomerItemID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Item #")]
        public string ItemID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "#,###")]
        public int? PriceUnit { get; set; }

        public string UnitID { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Quantity is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Item Quantity must be a whole Number")]
        [Range(1, 15000000, ErrorMessage = "Item Quantity must be between 1 - 15000000")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0}", NullDisplayText = "0")]
        public Int64? Quantity { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
        public Decimal? Price { get; set; }

        public Int64 BlanketOrderQuantity { get; set; }
        public Int64 ReleasedQuantity { get; set; }
        public Int64 RemainingQuanity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your controller action look like, I mean were the error was handled?

Comment: I think user send empty string, which become `null` and it is not `System.Int64`

Comment: The property, Quantity is a nullable of Int64.  This value is null when initially loaded, and yet it works then.

Comment: You might have to create your own editor template to support nullable long. See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html Editor Templates section

Comment: You need to set breakpoint and view your model. Controller receive `ReleaseModel`, but template uses `OrderLineItemModel`, maybe you will see some extra details.

Comment: @webdeveloper THat isn't the view, that is an editor template. The model behind the view is a ReleaseModel.  The ReleaseModel contains a list of OrderLineItemModel.  So my view contains this <tbody>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LineItems)      
            </tbody>

Comment: I understand this, but could you check your object under debbuger?

Comment: Check it for what? The variable type is Int64? I found it fails whenever there is a value. Succeeds when null

Comment: I would guess the problem is that `null` can be interpreted as a string by the template, but an actual int64 can't. And the template requires a string. But not 100% sure here, so not making an answer...

Comment: That's my guess too, as it appears as if the framework is trying to use a string template.  When the value is null, this works, as null can be safely cast to the model of string the template needs. When I have a value, it fails. However, there isn't a default template for Int64.  I'm not sure where to go from here. I may try creating a template for the type I need.

Comment: Just to remove some complexity from this, I changed the Quantity property to Int64 (no longer nullable).  I'm still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer to my own question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723782/how-can-i-pass-an-int-value-as-the-linktext-for-and-actionlink/10726097#10726097

You might be able to do this.

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => (string)m.Quantity.ToString() ?? 0)`

Comment: The Validation message isn't the problem. I can remove that completely and I still get the issue. The problem is that the EditorFor is trying to uses a string editor template and the property is of the datatype Long (Int64)